# how to change permissions to etc/hostfig

Tags: mysql, permissions

I'm trying to Delete MySQL from my Mac completely via my terminal. When I type in MySql to my terminal it still brings it up which in my opinion means it's still running.

I am trying to use etc/hostfig but it says:

/etc/hostconfig -bash: /etc/hostconfig: Permission denied

Any takers?

Comment: It's cool and yeah I got pretty pissed off... I use google all the time but sometimes it's good for someone to just say hey try this. I've considered paying for codeschool or tuts and have already build the blog example three times on guides.rubyonrails.org. I really appreciate you messaging back! @ParitoshPiplewar

Answer (score 0):

stop `mysql`  service
then type

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm /etc/my.cnf
```

source http://tomkeur.net/39/how-to-remove-mysql-completely-mac-os-x-leopard.html

Comment: sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
Password:
rm: /usr/local/mysql: No such file or directory                       This is what it returned.

Comment: @MikeOnWeb what does `whereis mysql` return